# CentOS 7 on VirtualBox Using 100% CPU

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, cpu, centos

I have CentOS 7 installed as a guest in a VirtualBox 4.3.18 virtual machine, with the latest guest additions installed too. The host operating system is OS X Yosemite running on my 2014 MacBook Pro 15".

**Guest Configuration:**

- CentOS 7
- Memory: 4096MB
- CPUs: 4 Processors with 80% execution cap, VT-x / Nested Pagin / PAE/NX enabled.
- Graphics: 3D acceleration is disabled; there is a nasty bug that hangs the guest if you have it enabled.

The system runs fine for about 20 minutes however it soon starts running all 4 CPU cores at 75% capacity, NON STOP. The CentOS 7 system monitor will show only a few processes running, using a total of 10% CPU, which is what it SHOULD be. For example `gnome-shell` and `gnome-system monitor` at 7% and 1% CPU respectively. NOTHING ELSE is actively executing, and yet all 4 processors are running at 74 - 80% capacity.

If I stop using the mouse, and just let things sit for 2-3 minutes, 3 of the 4 CPUS drop to 20% and the 4th remains at 76%.

To ensure the issue is not caused by VirtualBox, the host OS, or a device issue, I shut down the CentOS 7 guest, and ran a CentOS 6.5 guest with an identical configuration; it does not have any issues with over cpu utilization.

I'm starting to wonder if CentOS 7 has a rather nasty bug in the processor interface that is likely triggered by their attempts at "intelligent virtual environment processing" updates that went into the CentOS 7 release.

Any suggestions on how to further narrow down the issue, and submit a bug report to the CentOS team would be appreciated; System Monitor is not telling me much, nor are the standard #ps reports.

Comment: A hint... installed htop and it is showing process details that are NOT the same as the GUI System Monitor "gnome-system-monitor".  htop is clearly showing gnome-shell is the culprit.  Five (5) process are running gnome-shell at 333%, 81%, 76%, 76% and 76% CPU utilization.   CentOS 7 gnome-shell is burning up the CPU cores!  Next question... how do I determine what might be making gnome-shell "go crazy".     CentOS 6.5 gnome-shell behaves normally on this host/guest setup.

Comment: Another hint: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/centos-7-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage-4175516392/   "video drivers not configured correctly causing software graphic render v. hardware".    Likely related to disabling 3D rendering due to the highly unstable nature of 3D on this host/guest combination.   Oddly CentOS 6.5 3D rendering works like a charm and I have no issues like this with 6.5 3d rendering off.   Looks like a deep rabbit hole. :/